# We're using gitlab to store/share an npm package and I want to know how we can handle deploying

Tags: git, google-app-engine, deployment, ssh-keys

We are using a gitlab private repo to store and share a package. It's working great for development and all we need to share with our collaborators is their public ssh key, which we add to the project and that allows for install via:

`npm install git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/group/project#{commit-ish}`

However, this falls short when it comes to deploying. Is it possible to share a package in this way for use in production?

Additionally, we're deploying to App Engine and I'm not able to find any information about managing SSH Keys on App Engine - if it's possible and/or how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart-triggering-builds-with-source-repositories) to automate the deploy of your build to App Engine. Unfortunately, Gitlab is not yet supported by Cloud Build, but you could mirror the Gitlab repository to [Cloud Source Repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/://) and use Cloud Repositories as a trigger.

There is a great tutorial by Brian Michalski on [Cloud Source Repositories + GitLab](https://medium.com/@bamnet/cloud-source-repositories-gitlab-2fdcf1a8e50c).

To [integrate Cloud Repositories to Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/running-builds/automate-builds#creating_a_build_trigger) you must create a cloudbuild.yaml file inside the main app directory.

```
steps:
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy"]
timeout: "1600s"
```

Push this to the master.

Then go to the [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart-triggering-builds-with-source-repositories) page on the Console and create a trigger using Cloud Repositories and select the same repo as the one that is being mirrored to Gitlab.

About you inquiry about SSH keys on App Engine, that's because there isn't any. You can not SSH on App Engine Standard and you can only SSH to flexible only for debugging(once you SSH out of the instance and turn off debugging the instance get's restarted and every change is lost).

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try it out.

Comment: Hello, were you able to try it out? Did it work for you?